# Execute code when recieve push notification when app is not running

Tags: ios, swift, apple-push-notifications, uilocalnotification

I am working on a reminder app.The app will show notifications at particular times which is set by the user.I have used local notifications to show the reminder.

The problem is I want to run some codes when it receives the local notifications even if the user does not tap on the notification. Is there any way to do this in swift ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you should add method `application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceive notification: UILocalNotification)` inside your AppDelegate.swift. The code you want to be implemented should be there. The code will be executed even the user does not tap on the notification. But anyhow, the app should be running.
Here is an extract from apple docs:

> If
>   the app is not active in the foreground when the notification fires,
>   the system uses the information in the UILocalNotification object to
>   determine whether it should display an alert, badge the app icon, or
>   play a sound. If the app is running in the foreground, the system
>   calls this method directly without alerting the user in any way.
>
> You might implement this method in your delegate if you want to be
>   notified that a local notification occurred. For example, a calendar
>   app might use local notifications to alert the user to upcoming
>   events.
>
> If the user chooses to open the app when a local notification occurs,
>   the launch options dictionary passed to the
>   application(*:willFinishLaunchingWithOptions:) and
>   application(*:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:) methods contains the
>   localNotification key. This method is called at some point after your
>   delegate’s application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:) method.

Comment: This is the right answer. Just so it is clear to the OP, you can't have your logic fire if your application is in the background as @grigory-konovalov notes here. If your app is backgrounded they must tap the notification for your logic to occur.

Comment: Thanks for responding. Is there any way I can keep the app in background?? I need to configure the next notification when user receive the notification.

Comment: What do you mean saying "configure the next when user receive the notification"? There are two possibilities when the app in the background and the notification is recieved . The first one - user ignore notification and the second one - user tap on notification to open the app. In any case the notification handler in the app delegate will be fired before the app will be opened. Moreover, don't forget about viewWillAppear method - you can perform some actions depends on your app logic inside this method.

Comment: I recommend you to familiarize yourselves with https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/TheAppLifeCycle/TheAppLifeCycle.html

Comment: @GrigoryKonovalov what I need to do is, if the user ignore the notification I need to configure another notification to show the reminder again.any way I can do this?

Comment: You do not need to keep the app in background. If the user ignores the notification and you suppose that the app will remain inactive for a long period use repeatInterval property of UILocalNotification instance to set desirable period between notification. When the user finally launches the app you can reconfigure notifications inside viewWillAppear method. The rest of possibilities (user tap on notification, notification appears when the app is active,...) could be handled by application(:,didRecieve:) method

Comment: More information how to handle notification https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/SchedulingandHandlingLocalNotifications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH5-SW1

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation.